# Android Appbar with Tablayout makes app outside the screen?

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, tabview

I followed [this](https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Radio) to Add Tablayout to My activity

In the Same one I have Changed [HomeActivity](https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Radio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/view/activities/HomeActivity.java)

from `public class HomeActivity extends Activity` To `public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Now I am getting Like this

[image]

I want to Display Options menu in action bar But I am getting Two Action/App Bar layout

And the Complete layout is missing

1. All I need that Action bar and App Bar should combine
2. Some text Is missing I mean Its going out side of the Screen Even When I remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`If I keep this Every thing Is fine It is inside the Screen But its beside the Status bar But If I remove this Bottom Part of App is Missing

In my Previous apps everything is fine But due to Tablayout I am getting Lot of Issues... 
Can Any one suggest me on this kind...

**Update**

With Reference of user@sanatchandravanshi I haved added `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` and Also I have Added

I have Added This in my Code

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Now Every thing Is fine But My app is overlapping outside the screen...

This is my [XML](https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Radio/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_home.xml) in that If I keep this `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

I am getting Full app screen But Top page is Hiding beside status bar like this

[image]

But If I remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` Bottom side is overflowing outside the screen....

Like the above Image

Can Any one suggest me How to Get app to fit the same screen with Statusbar,Appbar,Tablayout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep your code as

> public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity

and just add below line to your `style.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

then best practice is to use `Toolbar` and customize your actionbar as you want.

Edit:

User like this:

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar mToolbar;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_detail);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.upload_gallery_app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}
```

create menu and use Menu like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_gallery_detail, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

**Update**

Put a LinearLayout (instead of CoordinatorLayout )
And Change your `XML` file like [this](http://dropbox.com/s/uvc6p5anyungo07/file.txt?dl=0)

Comment: If I add NoActionBar Options menu is missing

Comment: But it solved a part of my question please check my updated question once... Can you Help me on this my layout is going out of screen.... I have given XML also

Comment: Can you please put LinearLayout (instead of CoordinatorLayout ) as your rootview and add orientation as vertical or you can get the file from <a href="dropbox.com/s/uvc6p5anyungo07/file.txt?dl=0"; > here </a>.....i think this will help you....for me it worked.

that also may hide some part in the bottom then just put ViewPager inside the scrollview

Comment: Thanks Its worked How could I miss that Point.. Its problem with layout Thanks for your valuable time .... and valuable answer....

Answer (score 0):

You need to put no `AppTheme.NoActionBar` theme in manisfest for `AppCompatActivity` Like this :

**AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
           <activity
                android:name="view.activities.HomeActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                //Change Theme to this
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Put this theme in style

**style.xml**

```
  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: If I change the theme to `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` Here Option menu is missing... And Same bottom part of app is hiding ... Already My app is this theme only So I have added a new light theme..